# Smallest interval whose sum exceeds a threshold

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, array

In a non-negative 1D array `x`, we wish to find the shortest slice such that `x[start:end] > threshold`, with constraint that `start <= argmax(x) < end`. Must work with floats and integers.

Below is my approach, validated using a greedy search. Can it be improved in terms of speed?

**Update**: my motivation was not having to resort to Numba, but turns out Cython is a lightweight alternative that's acceptable -- [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842309/10133797) is x10+ faster than any vectorized approach I've come up with.

#### My approach

A sort of binary search to narrow down possibilities, followed by greedy search. Let `N=len(x)`, `c=argmax(x)`:

1. Use a sliding window of size `d` (diameter), sliding it by `d_shift`, left to right, while always enclosing `c`.
2. Initialize `d=N//2`, and `search_interval=N`. Let `d_min = d - search_interval`, etc. If

   - Found `d_shift` such that `sum > threshold`: lower `d` by `(d - d_min)//2` (big enough, try smaller)
   - Not found: increase `d` by `(d_max - d)//2` (too small, try bigger)
3. For each `d`, store `distance`. Terminate search when we get same `d` twice. Output of 2 is `d` with smallest `distance`.
4. Repeat 2-3 with `ceil(search_interval / 2)`
5. Repeat 4 until `search_interval < 2`.

The greedy search does above but takes all `d in range(N)`.

#### Example

```py
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0]
threshold = 3 + 4 + 9 + 7 - 1
```

I inserted print statements that show `d, distance` for each iteration, and final output:

```py
search_interval=11
5, 3
1, 13
8, 5
5 <--
search_interval=6
5, 3
2, 6
6, 3
3, 2
7, 4
3 <--
search_interval=3
3, 2
4, 1
2, 6
4 <--
search_interval=2
4, 1
3, 2
4 <--
```

yielding `x[start:end]`

```py
[3 4 9 7]
```

which is the correct subinterval.

#### Code

Two modifications to what I described: 1) faster `x[a:b].sum()` via `cumsum`; 2) greed search computes distance without `abs` since sign matters, but `exp_search` uses `abs` to favor "exploration".

```py
def fast_search(x, threshold):
    N, d, c = len(x), len(x)//2, np.argmax(x)
    search_interval = len(x)
    csumz = np.hstack([0, np.cumsum(x)])
    
    while search_interval >= 2:
        d_min = d - search_interval
        d_max = d + search_interval
        d = exp_search(csumz, N, threshold, c, d, d_min, d_max)
        search_interval //= 2

    return greed_search(x, threshold, (d - 4, d + 4))

def exp_search(csumz, N, threshold, c, d_init, d_min, d_max):
    d = d_init
    d_done, d_dists = [], []
    while True:
        d = min(max(d, 1), N)
        if d in d_done:
            break
        d_done.append(d)

        _d_dists = []
        for d_shift in range(d):
            start = max(c - d + d_shift + 1, 0)  # +1 to ensure start <= c < end
            end = min(start + d, N)
            sm = csumz[end] - csumz[start]
            _d_dists.append(abs(sm - threshold))
            if sm > threshold:
                d -= (d - d_min)//2
                break
        else:
            d += (d_max - d)//2
        d_dists.append(np.min(_d_dists))

    min_idx = np.argmin(d_dists)
    return d_done[min_idx]
```

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0])
threshold = 7 + 9 + 4 + 3 - 1

start, end = fast_search(x, threshold)
print(x[start:end])
```

[Live code](https://replit.com/@OverLordGoldDra/ClientsideGrotesqueAdministrators#main.py) (includes `greed_search`)

#### Improvements

Since originally posting:

1. Vectorized `d_shift` search, replaced looped `min` and `max` with one-time compute
2. Corrected some logic, introduced signed search to `exp_search` and use it for small `search_interval`
3. Introduced `faster_greed_search`, used it inside `fast_search`, still test against `greed_search`

Profiler now indicates majority of time occupied outside of function calls, so likely arithmetic and looping, though I rather not resort to Numba. Still too slow. -- [Updated code](https://replit.com/@OverLordGoldDra/PreemptiveSickInstructions#main.py), not optimized for readability, and is a bit imprecise (off within a margin)

#### Benchmarks

Shown `%timeit original() | %timeit improved() | N`:

```
189  µs | 306 µs  | 1e1
638  µs | 709 µs  | 1e2
4.84 ms | 1.72 ms |1e3
117  ms | 4.02 ms | 1e4
1.26 s  | 11.8 ms | 1e5
13.5 s  | 213 ms  | 1e6
```

Comment: Could you explain the algorithm behind `exp_search`? Adding some timing into your testing code shows that it performs really well when looking for an interval of size 1 but severely under performs otherwise.

Comment: @apilat It's under "My approach". Unsure what you mean by "severely under performs" but the second variant appears to be `O(n)`, just with a bad constant -- I've since coded a much faster non-vectorized approach in Cython, now linked.

Comment: [Decent answer to SO cross-post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72831210)